# How to sign third-party driver without using WinDDK?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, certificate

I have a third-party driver, but it won't install now. Before it was working in a Test Mode (without Driver Signature Enforcement), but now I see in a Device Manager that Windows could not start device because driver's certificate was revoked. Even in a Test Mode. Guess driver's signature got broken. Original author of driver is unavailable, but I have .sys and .inf files at hand.

Is it possible to overwrite original signatures of that driver and make it self-signed? What utilite may I use for it?

I have searched Internet, but most solutions involve using Windows Driver Development Kit, which is quite heavy.

Comment: No; Being unable to run unsigned or untrusted drivers is suppose to be difficult due to the potential malicious actions those type of drivers can take. One potential solution is trust the revoked certificate.  Have you tried that?  Trusting a revoked certificate is not something you actually do, using drivers digitally signed by trusted certificates, is the optimal solution.

Comment: Windows won't load the driver and start up the device, because Windows thinks that certificate is no longer valid. How do I specify that as a user I trust to that certificate? Before I was able to run that driver, only in test mode and it was fine for me.

Comment: You use the certificate manager to move the revoked certificate into trusted certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dseo13b.exe . Use it at your own risk, it solved question, but there is something special with it...